# Keeping track of Div Navigation Path in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single html page with many full page divs that are linked to one another. Users take nonlinear paths through the divs by clicking on links in each div.

I would like keep track of the path users take through the divs, so they can click on "back" links and regress through their path. Ideally, the URL would also link to the specific page and path that the user had taken.

Is there any way to do this without separating them into different html pages? Or any other recommendations for structuring nonlinear navigations in a single html page?

Comment: wat do u min by `nonlinear`?

Comment: please provide code example.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be clear on what you are trying to do because I dont understand what you mean by 'URL' and specific page...

But from what I understand you are saying, this should be fairly easy to do using Javascript... just keep track of your current div number and add the div names to an array as the user progresses through.

Then link your back links to a function that moves the page back to the previous div in the array.
**SOMETHING LIKE -- ( you would have to work on your forward logic ) **

```
 var paths = new Array();
var currentDivNumber = 0;

function moveForward(nameOfNextDiv) {
    //Make some logic to determine what step you are on - 
    //If you are not on your latest step - 
    paths.push(nameOfNextDiv);
    currentDivNumber++;
    //Your div showing code here ... something LIKE:
    $(nameOfNextDiv).show(); 
}

function moveBackward() {
    currentDivNumber--;
    //Show the div of the currentDivNumber in the array.
    $(paths[currentDivNumber]).show(); 
}
```

You would need to think about if the user goes back ( 1 or more steps ) and then moves forward to a new different div... you would probably have to drop all the elements from where the new path started.